# Conversion of distance matrix to Newick format

Tags: python, heatmap, biopython, etetoolkit

My ultimate aim is to make a plot which merges a heatmap and a phylogenetic tree. I have accomplished the heatmap and I have also found ETE2 package in BioPython which could help me merge the two kinds of plots, however ETE2 requires Newick format(tree like) rather than distance matrix (which I have) as input. Does anyone know of a module in BioPython to help me do this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in Biostars there is a [thread](https://www.biostars.org/p/92360/) about it. Which points to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17657426/2886003) to convert these formats and then following [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/etetoolkit/pXr4B71Ozt0) of the ETE mailing list.

I found [this converter](http://www.trex.uqam.ca/index.php?action=matrixToNewick&project=trex) online, I am not sure if it works for you.

---

Asking to find a tool is [offtopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and I just made a google research...